# GTK equivalent of Win32 PostMessage()

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am porting a Win32 application to a GTK+ application in C.

The UI registers a callback with another (non-ui) library.  The library invokes the callback when it requires some additional piece of information from the user.  The UI prompts for the user input and then invokes a different library 'setinfo' call when the user has entered the requested information.  The UI cannot block the library's callback waiting for the user input.

In Windows, this was handled by the callback posting a custom-message to the main window and returning immediately.  The main window would display a dialog to gather the user input and on apply would push this information back down via the 'setinfo'.

What would be the equivalent or preferred mechanism for accomplishing this in GTK?  That is, how can post some sort of custom message or event that will result in a dialog running out of GTK's main thread and return to the callback thread quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was [g_idle_add()](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add).

In the callback thread:

```
g_idle_add(MyPromptFunction, someData);
return;
```

This returns to the library. Then the main ui thread invokes MyPromptFunction from where I was able to display my dialog, gather the required information, and resubmit it to the library via SetInfo().

Answer (score 0):

So you have your UI, and the external library L. I think the proper solution is like this:

1. In the first callback, where L is calling into UI, you pop up a GtkDialog.
2. You don't call `gtk_dialog_run()`, which would make the dialog modal but block L.
3. When the dialog generates a response signal, you parse it and call back into `L.setinfo()`.
4. You close the dialog.

Comment: Should this work?  If I create the dialog from within the context of the library callback thread, I get the following crash when I call gtk_widget_show_all(dlg): "xcb_io.c:140: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `req == dpy->xcb->pending_requests' failed."  If I call this dialog creation out of the context of something else (e.g. a menu click) it works fine.